# Underscore.js - Condition in template

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a model with this fields:

- id
- title
- url

I would like to show url when title is empty. for this I write:

```
<%= if(feed.get('title') == ''){ %>
    <%= feed.get('url') %>
<%= }else{ %>
    <%= feed.get('title') %>
<%= } %>
```

but I got error.

How I can do this?

Comment: which error you retrieve?

Comment: You could use `print` for dense stuff like this: `<% if(feed.get('title') == '') { print(feed.get('url')); } else { ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your syntax is wrong.

`<%= %>` outputs things to your page.

When you want to execute javascript code you use `<% %>`.
And if you want to escape your HTML, you use `<%- %>`.

So your code should be

```
<% if(feed.get('title') == '' %>
    <%= feed.get('url') %>
<% }else{ %>
    <%= feed.get('title') %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<% if (feed.get('title') === '') { %>
    <%= feed.get('url'); %>
<% } else { %>
    <%= feed.get('title'); %>
<% } %>
```

From underscore source:

```
evaluate    : /<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
interpolate : /<%=([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
escape      : /<%-([\s\S]+?)%>/g
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be of some help while practising underscore's templates, a simple [Underscore Template Editor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/underscore-template-editor).

Comment: Seems like a link to the resource is broken.

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk It's a small demo submitted by me on MDN :). But MDN is under maintenance. :(. [site] (https://developer.mozilla.org/) says `MDN should return to normal operations by 22:00 UTC.`